# Explain why $S$ is not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Explain why $S$ is not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

$S=\{(1, 3, 0),(4, 1, 2),(-2, 5, -2)\}$

I set this equal to an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$

After solving I got the matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 & -2 \\ 3 & 1 & 5 \\ 0 & 2 & -2\end{bmatrix}$

And since the $det(A)=0$ this set does not span $\mathbb{R}^3$.  However, I don't understand the answer the solution gave. It says:

> A basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ contains three linearly independent vectors. Because $-2(1, 3, 0)+(4, 1, 2)+(-2, 5, -2)=(0, 0, 0)$
>
> $S$ is linearly dependent and is, therefore, not a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$

However, if I test for linear independence I get the following $rref(A)$:

$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Which would imply to me that $S$ is linearly independent given the $0$ column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RREF tells you that $S$ is linearly independent.  What you have done is row-reduced the augmented matrix:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 4 & -2 & 0\\
3 & 1 & 5 & 0\\
0 & 2 & -2 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
to the reduced row echelon form
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
What this tells you is that the matrix formed by setting the columns equal to the given vectors of $S$ has non-trivial nullspace, meaning there exist constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$ not all $0$, such that $c_1 (1,3,0) + c_2(4,1,2) + c_3(-2,5,-2) = (0,0,0)$

What we will have done is effectively checked whether the 3 vectors given satisfy the definition of linear independence.  Since we have nonzero constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$ so that $c_1 (1,3,0) + c_2(4,1,2) + c_3(-2,5,-2) = (0,0,0)$, they are not linearly independent.

In fact, by simply backsolving and picking $c_3 = 1$, we could choose $c_2 = 1$, $c_1 = -2$

That implies that $\{(1,3,0),(4,1,2),(-2,5,-2)\}$ are linearly *dependent*, as the solution in the book states.  And 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ if and only if they are linearly independent, so the 3 vectors given are not a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

I previously said that this is because you have a row of zeros.  Technically, this is wrong.  The correct explanation has to do with pivot columns, namely that we have a non-leading non-pivot column on the LHS when reducing to row echelon form.  A row of zeros is enough if you are dealing with a square matrix, but seeing as that is rarely the case, you will want to know the more general method.

Say you have $4$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^6$.  These are linearly independent if and only if the matrix formed with the vectors has rank $4$.  Another way to verify this is that if each and every column on the LHS of the augmented matrix (when reduced to row echelon form) is a pivot column, then the column vectors forming your matrix are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!  This is what I was looking for.

Comment: You are quite welcome.  I went ahead and elaborated a bit on what the mechanics are behind seeing whether 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, or for that matter, any set of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (equivalently, linearly independent).  In practice, set the vectors up as columns in a matrix, and row-reduce to compute the nullspace of the matrix.  If the nullspace is nontrivial (i.e., if the nullspace contains a nonzero vector), then the vectors are linearly dependent, and cannot be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Strictly speaking the explanation given in this question is not correct: it is the non-leading (non-pivot) column on the LHS that shows the vectors are dependent, not the zero row.  For example, if two vectors in ${\Bbb R}^3$ lead to an echelon form$$\pmatrix{1&2\cr0&3\cr0&0\cr}\ ,$$then the vectors are independent despite the zero row.  If the LHS is a *square* matrix, as in the OP, it comes to the same thing, but usually it doesn't.

Comment: Corrected.  I was admittedly dealing specifically with the case $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (as in checking whether $n$ vectors form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$), but as this usually is not the case, I should not have left that as the main reason for seeing this.  It just happens to work if the LHS is square.

Answer (score 1):

Because

$$ 2(1,3,0) - (4,1,2) = (-2,5,-2) $$

Comment: Was the method I used incorrect?  How would I have gotten your answer?

Comment: A basis is a set of vectors that span the vector space $V$ and is a linearly independent set. In this case $V = \mathbb{R}^3$, and your set of vectors is not linearly independent because of what I wrote.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying, but how would I have gotten to your answer since I didn't see it?  Are there mechanics to finding this answer that you used or is it just something you spotted by examining the vectors?

Comment: there is not a machine to do that. Just see your vectors and play with them.

Comment: your solution is correct. You can put them in a matrix, and if the det is $0$, then they are not linearly independent

Answer (score 1):

This is an amplification of Lemur's answer, expanding on the "see your vectors and play with them" in his comment.  We want to know if we can find scalars $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that
$$\alpha(1,3,0)+\beta(4,1,2)+\gamma(-2,5,-2)=(0,0,0)\ .$$
But looking at the third component gives immediately $\beta=\gamma$.  So the previous equation can be written as
$$\alpha(1,3,0)+\beta(2,6,0)=(0,0,0)\ ,$$
and now it is easy to see that $\alpha=2$, $\beta=-1$ is a solution.  So
$$2(1,3,0)-(4,1,2)-(-2,5,-2)=(0,0,0)\ ,$$
which shows that the vectors are linearly dependent.